# Does the following tag question sound natural? “Seems like it’s no longer possible, is it?”

Tags: grammaticality, question-tags

I'm not sure if it is actually a tag question though. Because if it were a tag question then most probably, there should be *doesn’t it* at the end of it.

But that’s not what I want to ask the person I’m asking the question; rather, I want to ask them whether or not ***it*** is still possible.

If that construction is not possible, then how would you word it?

Comment: I would use *Seems like it's no longer possible, doesn't it?* or *Seems like it's no longer possible, or is it?*

Comment: Why not just ask "Do you think it's still possible?"?

Comment: @ArmthegoodguysinAmerica this low-quality question is highly unlikely to receive a formal answer, and the system normally auto-deletes an unanswered zero-score question if it's more than a year old. However, that code only works if there's *fewer than two comments*. If you delete yours, and I delete this one, we can help the system clean out some of the "dead wood" in our EL&U library. :-)

Comment: um, whatever...